# Can not find the virtualenv command after pip3 installed

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I use the `pip3` install the `virtualenv` in my CentOS7.2:

```
[root@www abc]#  pip3 install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (15.1.0)
[root@www abc]# virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
-bash: virtualenv: do not find the command
```

But I can not use it, there do not find the command.

Comment: Are you working with the pre-installed `pip3`? Using Anaconda should relieve most of your such problems (unless you are restricted against using it).

Comment: `which python` and `python -V` commands output please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using virtualenv, try running `python3 -m venv`. So to create a new virtualenv, just do `python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/my_virtualenv`.

As for why you can't find `virtualenv` by just typing it in, I guess that it's because `virtualenv.py` script is somewhere in `/usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages` - probably at `/usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py` - try running it directly.

`pip` is just a Python packaging utility. It's not responsible for adding tools into your `PATH` environment variable, or for installing utilities in your system.

If you want `virtualenv` command to be present in your system, I would recommend to install it using your system package manager instead. I would recommend to just use the built-in [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module instead.

Comment: `pip` also can install programs/utilities, not just packages and libraries!

Comment: Yes it does, but I've never seen a case where they added themselves to `PATH` automatically. The path where they install their scripts should be added to `$PATH` already, but it's clearly not the case for the author of this question.